# Smoothly changing jQuery animations

Tags: jquery, animation, performance

in relation to a question I asked last night, which got only one answer, I have a question about jQuery animations. If I want to quit one animation at some point, determined by an arbitrary event, and begin another animation with a different speed, is there any way to make that change unnoticeable?

In other words, if the animation starts at 4000ms, then the user moves the mouse and the first animation quits, and a second begins, this one at 2000ms, is there any way to avoid that jerky horrible pause before the second animation begins?

I'm using .stop(true) on the element to stop whatever animation is currently running before I begin the second, but it isn't helping, and .clearQueue() only fires when the event has completed.

As requested, here's the code:

`$(document).ready(function(){`

```
    $('#innerMainbottom').hover(function(){

        $('#innerMainbottom').mousemove(function(e){

            var mouseX = e.pageX-$(this).offset().left,

                width = $(this).innerWidth(),           // the width is 1000, but the container to move is 1600, hidden by overflow:hidden

                speed = (width-mouseX)*10,

                sliderCont = $('#sliderCont');          // this is the container I want to move



        if(mouseX>=510&&mouseX<=960){                       // do this if the user hovers to the right half of the container


            moverRight(mouseX,width,speed,sliderCont);
        }



        else if(mouseX>=0&&mouseX<=460){                        // do this if the user hovers to the left half of the container


            moverLeft(mouseX,width,speed,sliderCont);
        }



        else if(mouseX>460&&mouseX<510){                // stop altogether if the user hovers in the centre of the container, emulating a pausing effect



            $('#sliderCont').stop(true);


        }


        });



    function moverRight(mX,w,s,sC){


        $(sC).stop(true).animate({'left':-1600+'px'},s);


    }



    function moverLeft(mX,w,s,sC){


        $(sC).stop(true).animate({'left':0+'px'},s);


    }


    },function(){


        $('#sliderCont').stop(true).animate({'left':0+'px'},'normal');


    });



});
```

Comment: can you post the code to see this jerky move you are describing

Answer (score 0):

I've found the smoothest way to perform any sort of jQuery animation is to use callback functions, and wait until the animations themselves are over. For example, if you want to slide an element up, and then fade out, instead of chaining the functions together like:

```
.slideUp().fadeOut();
```

I've found that doing

```
$("#anything").slideUp(1000, function() {
   $(this).fadeOut(1000);
})
```

Produces a smoother animation.

For a more direct answer to your question, using stop() does not produce the smoothest animation "stopping" because it literally cuts it off (anywhere along the animation chain). You could use `.delay()` to produce a short stoppage as well in between animation chains.

Comment: Thanks dude, but the thing is I want the user to be able to control speed simply by hovering. Imagine a line, the further up the line the user hover the faster the animation. Even if I pick a few spots along the line and double the speed at those points. Now, I can easily change animation speed, but stopping one animation function and simultaneously starting another is proving a pain in the gluteous maximus.